# Count number of pixel for each polygon and have the data in one featurecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel, count, reducers

I have raster with NDVI values. I have calculate for each plot the number of pixels in different values (no. of poixels lower than 0.2, higher than 0.2 and lower than 0.4 ect....)  based on masks I have created.
My problem is that now I compute it for the polygons and create each time new featurecolelction that contains this count data.
I would like to have one featurecollection that has the data of the counting for each mask layer.

Here you can see my code and try it, the raster and the polygon suppose to be available.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/675b9c9329db3c8e1d556ee577443173

My end goal: To have one Featurecollection which will contain serveral columns, one column on each "count" process with the " maineMeansFeatures" calclations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single `reduceRegions()` call, using `ee.Reducer.group()`. Though it require some fiddling. I'm sure there are more concise ways to do this, but here goes:

```
var featureCollection = test_ir;
var classifications = [ 
  {className: 'lt02', classValue: 1, image: raster.lt(0.2)},
  {className: 'bt0204', classValue: 2, image: raster.gte(0.2).and(raster.lt(0.4))},
  {className: 'bt0406', classValue: 3, image: raster.gte(0.4).and(raster.lt(0.6))},
  {className: 'gt06', classValue: 4, image: raster.gt(0.6)}
]

// Dictionary mapping classValue to className
var classNameByValue = classifications.reduce(
  function (acc, classification) {
    return acc.set('' + classification.classValue, classification.className)
  }, 
  ee.Dictionary()
)

// Single band classification, where the value of the band is the classValue
var classification = classifications
  .reduce(
    function (acc, classification) {
      return acc.add(
        classification.image.multiply(classification.classValue)
      )
    }, 
    ee.Image(0)
  )  

// Dictionary mapping className to 0
var zeroByClassName = classifications.reduce(
  function (acc, classification) {
    return acc.set(classification.className, 0)
  },
  ee.Dictionary()
)

// The final counts features, with count by className
var counts = classification
  .addBands(classification)
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: featureCollection,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count()
     // Groups the count by classValue
      .group({groupName: 'classValue'}),
    scale: 20,    
  })  
  .map(function (feature) {
    var groups = ee.List(feature.get('groups'))
    var properties = groups.iterate(
      function (group, acc) {
        group = ee.Dictionary(group)
        acc = ee.Dictionary(acc)
        var classValue = group.get('classValue')
        var className = classNameByValue.get(classValue)
        var count = group.get('count')
        return acc.set(className, count)
      },
      // Make sure we get all classNames, if they are in the geometry or not.
      zeroByClassName 
    )
    return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), properties)
  })

Map.addLayer(classification, {min: 1, max: classifications.length, palette: 'blue,green,yellow,red'})
print('counts', counts)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/70f3ea61138d08d444ef835a377f6a9f

Comment: thank you very much. I would love to understand better what you have done: What does the acc means?what is the ' ' part in the acc.set?  why do you change the classname to 0? what is the groups variable?

Comment: also I have tried to add mean class as yo u can see here but for some reason I get error "raster.mean is not a function" ,The  same when I want to have the count. I believe it's because I don't understand the function so well https://code.earthengine.google.com/51a0c9787d654e380c15984e9eb97bc9

Comment: `acc`: Read the `ee.List.iterate()` docs. I have a bad habit of calling the accumulator argument `acc`, instead of using a more semantic name. In this code, making things confusing, I have used both server-side `ee.List.iterate()`, and the more-or-less equivalent client-side function `Array.reduce()`. Don't mix this latter function up with any of the server-side `reduce()` functions.

Comment: `acc.set('' + classification.classValue, ...)`: Here, acc is an `ee.Dictionary`. The key argument in `ee.Dictionary.set()` must be a string. `'' + number` is an easy way to convert a client-side number into a string.

Comment: `why do you change the classname to 0`: Not sure what you mean, but if you're referring to `zeroByClassName`, it's just a dictionary where the keys are class names, and the values are 0. When exporting feature collections, they all must have the same columns. `zeroByClassName` is used to add class names missing from a geometry, and assign them a zero count.

Comment: `groups`: A list of dictionaries with `classValue` and `count` as keys. It's generated by `ee.Reducer.group()`.

Comment: `raster.mean()`: The `classifications` list is a list of binary classifications, where the images have 0 or 1 as values. The mean you're adding is not a classification.